# Problem with building in Android Studio when opening in another computer

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, manifest

I tried to use a Program in another computer and Android Studio Couldnt Build. 
This build worked fine on another Android Studio and was builded succesfully, its probabbly something I didnt update or something like that.

I cant find where the error is, if you can help I would appredciate it, ty.

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.usuario.tm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'




 // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usuario.tm">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Naranja">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: attribute 'android:name' in <instrumentation> tag must be a valid Java class name.

  Command: C:\Users\Juancho\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\cfcffe7ed65bf8e3d18c451094195793\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Juancho\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestResources\out\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\resources-list-for-resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestResources\r\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:9: AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in <instrumentation> tag must be a valid Java class name.

  Command: C:\Users\Juancho\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\cfcffe7ed65bf8e3d18c451094195793\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\Juancho\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestResources\out\resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugAndroidTestResources\resources-list-for-resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debugAndroidTest\processDebugAndroidTestResources\r\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads\TM\app\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild on another computer?

Comment: Using `C:\Users\Juancho\Downloads` as your work directory can be inconsistent due to the browser or other processes deleting files due to space issues. Suggest moving your project into a directory like `Documents\<project_name>` and clean and rebuild there.

Comment: clear all caches, clean and build by commenting out this line   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3" and try to build. If it success, you need to change version or instrumentation files